# Use Travis CI to build python distribution and upload to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: travis-ci, artifactory

I would like to use Travis CI to build and publish distributions to Artifactory.  Does anyone have an example configuration that does anything like this they could share?  I'm trying to put the pieces together, but I'm new to Travis and it's hard to see what goes on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that working with the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI), which is made for exactly such use cases.

You will have to download and configure it as part of your travis build steps.

Install

```
curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh
```

Configure (assume you have the needed environment variables set)

```
jfrog rt config --url ${RT_URL} --user ${RT_USER} --apikey ${RT_API_KEY}
```

Now you just run your build and upload the results with (see docs for full details)

```
jfrog rt u ...
```

Comment: Asis Thanks for the pointer.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's of help to anyone else, I'm posting the pertinent section of my working .travis.yml config based on @Eldad Asis's answer.  (For some reason, I couldn't get `upload` to use the system I'd `config`'d correctly, so that is commented out and replaced below)

```
script:
- virtualenv buildwheel
- . buildwheel/bin/activate
- python setup.py sdist
- curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh
# - jf config add <my_server> --artifactory-url ${RT_URL} --user ${RT_USER} --access-token ${RT_API_KEY}
# - jf rt upload --server-id <my_server> --flat=true dist/\* <my_repository>/
- jf rt upload --url ${RT_URL} --user ${RT_USER} --access-token ${RT_API_KEY} --flat=true dist/\* <my_repository>/
- deactivate
```

Thanks again, Eldad!